# How can I find string parameters in text by cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database that I’ve saved some  `:Post` and `:HashTag` nodes in that. 
`:Post` node has properties `id` and `text`. `:HashTag` node has properties `id` and `tag` (tag here is the name or text of `HashTag`).

`:HashTag` nodes are all lower case and start by `#`.
I want to write a query that whenever I’m creating new `Post` that contains the current `HashTag`  in the database in it,  it automatically finds `HashTag` in the `text` property of `:Post` node and make a relation Like this:

```
(:Post)<-[:TAG]-(:HashTag)
```

For example I’m creating the `:Post` :
`Today is #friday, ready for the #weekend`

I have `weekend` hashTag in my database but not `friday`.
So I’ll have a relation `TAG` between this `:Post` and `weekend` hashTag and nothing to do with `friday` hashTag.

But if I have this `:Post`:

`Chrismats #holiday , and #traveling`

Here I have both `#holiday` and `#traveling` as `:HashTag` in my database so I would have one `TAG` relation between this `:Post` and `#holiday` and one `TAG` relation between this `:Post` and `#travelling`

Any idea how can I write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661113/9161843 as I was searching for the solution by code:

```
function getHashTags(postText) {
  const regex = /#[^\s!$%^&*+.,£#]+/gm;
  const selectedHashTag = [];
  const subStr = postText.split(' ');
  const checkHashTag = _.filter(subStr, word => word.startsWith('#') || word.includes('#'));

  checkHashTag.map((hashTags) => {
    if (hashTags.match(regex)) {
      hashTags.match(regex).map(hashTag => selectedHashTag.push(hashTag.substr(1)));
    }
    return true;
  });
  return selectedHashTag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do some text processing here, first using `split()` around whitespace to get a list of words, filtering only for words starting with '#', and then cleaning the word (to convert to lowercase and remove punctuation and non-alphanumeric characters). You'll need [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to use the clean function

You can do an UNWIND on the list (so each word will be on its own row), MATCH to a :HashTag node with the given name, and create the relationship.

```
... // assume you just created post:Post with text, with post and text still in scope
WITH post, [tag in split(text, ' ') WHERE tag STARTS WITH '#' | apoc.text.clean(tag)] as tagWords
UNWIND tagWords as tagWord
MATCH (tag:HashTag {tag:tagWord})
CREATE (tag)-[:TAG]->(post)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it's working but finally, I've found that I can use js code for extracting the `HashTags` and I'm gonna post the code but I've marked your answer as useful