# How can I set a regex for special condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I need help for writing a regex pattern fo these conditions:

#### Limitations on Hashtag Characters

*Length*

- You only need to add a # before a word to make it hashtag. However, because a Tweet is only limited to under 140 characters, the best hashtags are those composed of a single word or a few letters. Twitter experts recommend keeping the keyword under 6 characters.
- Use only numbers and letters in your keyword. You may use an underscore but do this sparingly for aesthetic reasons. Hyphens and dashes will not work.
- No Spaces

  Hashtags do not support spaces. So if you're using two words, skip the space. For example, hashtags for following the US election are tagged as #USelection, not $US election.
- No Special Characters

  Hashtags only work with the # sign. Special characters like "!, $, %, ^, &, *, +, ." will not work. Twitter recognizes the pound sign and then converts the hashtag into a clickable link.
- HashTags can start by numbers
- Hashtags can be in any language
- Hashtags can be emojis or symbols

I came up by the idea like this but it's not including the last two conditions:

```
const subStr = postText.split(/(?=[\s:#,+/][a-zA-Z\d]+)(#+\w{2,})/gm);

const result = _.filter(subStr, word => word.startsWith('#')).map(hashTag => hashTag.substr(1)) || [];
```

### EDIT:

Example: If I have:

```
const postText = "#hello12#123 #hi #£hihi #This is # #Hyvääpäivää #Dzieńdobry #जलवायुपरिवर्तन an #example of some text with #hash-tags - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link,#hashtag1,hi #123 hfg skjdf kjsdhf jsdhf kjhsdf kjhsdf khdsf kjhsdf kjhdsf hjjhjhf kjhsdjhd kjhsdfkjhsd #lasthashtag";
```

Result should be:

```
["hello12", "123", "hi", "This", "", "Hyvääpäivää", "Dzieńdobry", "जलवायुपरिवर्तन", "example", "hash", "anchor", "hashtag1", "123", "lasthashtag"]
```

What I have now:

```
["hello12", "123", "hi", "This", "Hyv", "Dzie", "example", "hash", "anchor", "hashtag1", "123", "lasthashtag"]
```

Note: I don't want to use JavaScript library.

Thanks

Comment: Keeping things simple, what would be wrong with `^#\S+$` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen it's just returning the exact `text` that I want to check

Comment: @Nafis What would you like/expect it to return instead?

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the characters that are not allowed in a hashtag are `!$%^&*+.` (the ones you mentioned) and `,` (based on your example), you can use the following regex pattern:

```
/#[^\s!$%^&*+.,#]+/gm
```

**[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/3egL8z/1).**

Note: To exclude more characters, you can add them in the character class as I did above. Obviously, you can't rely on alphanumeric characters only because you want to support other Unicode symbols and emojis.

**JavaScript code sample:**

```js
const regex = /#[^\s!$%^&*+.,#]+/gm;
const str = "#hello12#123 #hi #£hihi #This is # #Hyvääpäivää #Dzieńdobry #जलवायुपरिवर्तन an #example of some text with #hash-tags - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link,#hashtag1,hi #123 hfg skjdf kjsdhf jsdhf kjhsdf kjhsdf khdsf kjhsdf kjhdsf hjjhjhf kjhsdjhd kjhsdfkjhsd #lasthashtag";
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    m.forEach((match) => {
        console.log("Found match: " + match);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks tones, I've used your pattern and it's working for me. I've made your answer as `Answer` and also `Useful`

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution without `while` that worked for me and Thanks [@Ahmed Abdelhameed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4934172/ahmed-abdelhameed) for the pattern :

```
function getHashTags(postText) {
  const regex = /#[^\s!$%^&*+.,£#]+/gm;
  const selectedHashTag = [];
  const subStr = postText.split(' ');
  const checkHashTag = _.filter(subStr, word => word.startsWith('#') || word.includes('#'));

  checkHashTag.map((hashTags) => {
    if (hashTags.match(regex)) {
      hashTags.match(regex).map(hashTag => selectedHashTag.push(hashTag.substr(1)));
    }
    return true;
  });
  return selectedHashTag;
}
```